# How to get a flex item to fill the width of the parent div

Tags: css, flexbox, frontend, tailwind-css, width

Im trying to get an input to fill a flex containers width , I've tried adding w-full to the input , i've tried adding grow to the input as its a flex child and i'ver had no success yet. This is the first project i am doing in my free time to teach myself tailwind so apologies if this is a trivial question but it seems to have me stumped.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjU6Q.jpg)

The input at the under the picture and the text i want to span the width of the entire red bg.

The html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        @vite('resources/css/app.css')
    </head>
    <body class="">
        <nav class="relative container bg-red-500 mx-auto p-6">
            <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
            <div class="pt-4 mx-auto">
                <p class="text-white" >
                    Morelate
                </p>
            </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <section class="flex h-screen">
            <div class="container items-center justify-center flex flex-col mx-auto my-auto bg-red-500">
                <div class="flex flex-row w-3/4 rounded-full my-auto">
                    <div class="flex mx-auto w-1/2">
                        <img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/wo2hJpn04vbtmh0B9utCFdsQhxM.jpg" id="posterImage" class="h-80 rounded-lg drop-shadow-2xl" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="flex flex-col space-y-12 w-1/2 items-center">
                        <h1>Leonardo DiCaprio</h1>
                        <p>Famous Actor</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                    <input type="input" class="rounded-full w-full border-black border-4">
            </div>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

I've tried adding w-full to the input , i've tried adding grow to the input as its a flex child and i'ver had no success yet. This is the first project i am doing in my free time to teach myself tailwind so apologies if this is a trivial question but it seems to have me stumped.

Comment: The input is full width, use your browsers dev tools to see what's causing the issue. https://play.tailwindcss.com/m2aTjnjoVu. You could potentially be using an incorrect version of tailwind.

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<meta>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/semantics.html#the-meta-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification. The same is true for `<img>` and every other HTML tag.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.